# How to dynamically render information in javascript mapping function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, mapping

So I have an interesting problem. I have a JavaScript table (this is located in a React JS component). I am using a mapping function to loop through an array, which is stored in props. The value of each element of the array is used to create an options tag for a select drop down menu. Please see the following code:

```js
<table className="addNewTransactionTable">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <label>#</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label>Account</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label>Description</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label>Debit</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label>Credit</label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label>Name</label>
    </th>
  </tr>
  {rows.map((item) => (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder={item}></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="accountName" value={this.state.accountName} onChange={this.onChangeAccount}>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          {this.props.accountArray.map((index) => (
            <option>{index.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Description"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Debit"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Credit"></input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

This is creating a line of input values, depending on how many lines the user chooses. See the following picture for reference:
[image]
The first mapping function represents the number of lines the user chose, and the second mapping function represents all of the options of each drop-down menu (which is one of the fields in the lines that are generated). My problem is with the drop-down menu. When I select one option in one of the lines, it changes the selection in the drop-down menu on ALL the lines. This is because the value attribute is pointing to the same state value. Is there a way I can change the state dynamically for each loop of the mapping function? One idea I had was to make `this.state.accountName` an array, and change the element it points to with each loop. However, I am not super familiar with the mapping function. Is this possible in order to create a dynamic state? If not, is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would probably go with creating a dropdown component, so each component can manage it's own state rather than trying to do it all in the parent.

Comment: Please share your state part as well. how you are currently managing state.

Comment: @Nick that is a very good idea...not exactly sure why that idea never crossed my mind. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution, just provide key={} to each option

```
 this.props.accountArray.map((item, index)=> <option key={index}>{item.name}</option>)) }
```

In onAccountChange method, you can do something like this

```
onAccountChange = (event,) => {
  let value = event.target.value;
let selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
  this.setState({ ...state, type[selectedIndex]: value)}
}
```

Do something like this either save it in an object

Comment: Why would this work? assuming the issue here is because he is setting the `account` state of the parent component every time he makes a selection, and every dropdown uses this state to render a value.

Comment: This solution does not work. This does not fix my issues with state.

Comment: @LukeSharon My solution didn't work because there are multiple issues with this code. You are using the controlled element you will have to manage your state accordingly. When you don't use a key React thinks every element is the same.

Comment: The issue related to his problem had nothing to do with `key` in React, that is for React's internal update mechanism.

Comment: That was a fault I mentioned related to bad code alongside the original issue. Although it's your wish, you probably would be more experienced. Thanks, I am not here to argue people